# Angular Dart "reorder-list" component use example

Tags: dart, angular-material2, angular-dart

I am using Dart SDK 2.0.0-dev.55.0 with angular_components ^0.9.0-alpha+13.

I am attempting to use:
https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_components/angular_components/ReorderListComponent-class

Are there any links to examples of how this component is used?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help for how to ask good questions.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Significantly revised.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example should contain an example for every component.

Comment: Thanks @GunterZochbauer. I had a look there. I could not see an example for `<reorder-list>`.

Comment: I see. They reworked the page and now I can't fine one either. Can you please create an issue in the examples GitHub repo to get it re-added?

Comment: This is a reference to an older commit, might provide what you want https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/tree/8aeb65256c33d6a3b31c27ed7c0010d17f089ec2/lib/src/reorder_list_demo

Comment: Issue raised:    https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/issues/90

Comment: Also, thanks @GunterZochbauer, the old commit is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I will close the question when the example is re-instated. In the meantime I will use the old one to understand how it works. Thanks again.